# Rounded Edges with Box Shadow - Tailwind CSS

Tags: css, tailwind-css

I'm trying to make a slight tweak to my button borders using box shadows but am unsure how.

The following Tailwind.css customization creates the following button border below:

```js
boxShadow: {
  'outline': '3px 3px 0px #777, -3px -3px 0px #777, -3px 3px 0px #777, 3px -3px 0px #777',
}
```

[image]

As you can see, it isn't *quite* right on the left and right edges, where there's a slight curl in which they don't perfectly align. Does anyone know how to fix this so that it's perfectly round around the entire border?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use spread parameter of box-shadow property

```css
button
{
background:white;
padding:10px 30px;
border-radius:20px;
border:none;
box-shadow:0 0 0 4px rgba(0,0,0,1);
}
```

```html
<button>Button Test</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use this if you're using TailwindCSS.

```
<button type="button" className="m-10 py-2.5 px-7 shadow-[0_0_0_4px_rgba(0,0,0,1)] rounded-full" >Button Test</button>
```

**Result** :

[image: Rounded corner button]